# The crash due to Facebook SDK 5.0 on Android 4.X

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Here is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.facebook.appevents.internal.InAppPurchaseEventManager.invokeMethod(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:618)
       at com.facebook.appevents.internal.InAppPurchaseEventManager.isBillingSupported(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:223)
       at com.facebook.appevents.internal.InAppPurchaseEventManager.getPurchases(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:395)
       at com.facebook.appevents.internal.InAppPurchaseEventManager.getPurchasesInapp(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:231)
       at com.facebook.appevents.internal.InAppPurchaseActivityLifecycleTracker$2$1.run(InAppPurchaseActivityLifecycleTracker.java:120)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I only import `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'` in gradle.build for Firebase Facebook Auth.

Anyway I can let my app work with Android 4.X and also keep Facebook SDK for Auth? Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, The root cause is because of a deprecated method.
As per the changelog of Facebook, [Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

the method `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(Context)` has been deprecated. Hence, it was crashing internally.
Alternately `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(Application)` should be used. This solved the crash for us.